# Xamarin Android simulator screen contents do not rotate

Tags: xamarin.android

In Xamarin, when I rotate the Android simulator, screen contents are not rotating according to the new screen orientation. There's no orientation locking in the `MainActivity` set.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have rotated your simulator, on the navigation buttons bar

[image: Navigation button bar]

there is a flashing square icon appears, and you need to click on it, and then simulator screen contents will be updated.

[image: animated-demo]